# How to get MM/dd/yyyy kk:mm seperately from MM/dd/yyyy kk:mm in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date

How to get date and time separately from date time in SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy kk:mm");

I am able to generate current date and time together using simpledateformat. But i am not able to get the date and time seperately from that for my use case.

```
    Date d = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy kk:mm");
dateTimeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Mountain"));
String dateTime = dateTimeFormat.format(d);
```

This is what i am doing. It gives the date time together. How to get date and time separately?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ? Shouldn't this be simple to solve by creating two SimpleDateFormat objects, one with the date specifiers and the other with the time? or am I grossly over-simplifying this?

Comment: I want to get date and time from the above specified object. I don't want to create separately because i am using datetime together at several places in my code. FYI, I know how to create separately.

Comment: You can get the date and the time separately from the same Date object, but this ***requires***, no it ***absolutely*** requires that you use two SimpleDateFormat objects. This is a truth regardless of your desires (if you have to use the old Date class)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated (the former in particular notoriously troublesome). Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also I’m in doubt whether you want `kk` for hour of day since it will print 00 as 24, I have never seen that used (if you’re on Android, it may be different).

Comment: `US/Mountain` is a deprecated time zone ID. You should use `America/Denver` instead (provided that that’s what you want, it will it least give you the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use java.time API instead, so for example to get the Date and Time separately you can use :

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("US/Mountain");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime();
```

If you want to get the format you want you can use :

```
String ld = zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy"));
String lt = zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("kk:mm"));
```

Outputs

```
04/05/2019
13:20
```